# looping over dataframes...and why this is the wrong approach

Tags: r

Let's say I have several dataframes and I want to loop through the rows of each dataframe and do something, like send an SMS message using the `httr` package. I could create several loops, but I suspect the answer is "don't use loops!".

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=2:11, C=3:12) # imagine these columns hold words and phone numbers
df2 <- data.frame(A=4:13, B=5:14, C=6:15)

# loop for df1
for (n in 1:nrow(df1)) { # imagine that each row is a person
  # get details for each person (row)
  sms1 <- df1$A[n]
  sms2 <- df1$B[n]
  sms3 <- df1$C[n]
  # create personalized message to send
  sms <- paste(sms1, sms2, sms3, sep=" ")
  # here I would use the POST() function of httr to send a personalized SMS to each person, but that is not important
}

# loop for df2
for (n in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  sms1 <- df2$A[n]
  sms2 <- df2$B[n]
  sms3 <- df2$C[n]
  sms <- paste(sms1, sms2, sms3, sep=" ")
  # here I would use the POST() function of httr to send a personalized SMS, but that is not important
}
```

But what I really want to do is create an outer loop to loop through each dataframe. Something like:

```
dfs <- c("df1", "df2")
# loop over dfs
for (d in dfs) {
  for (n in 1:nrow(d)) {
    sms1 <- d$A[n]
    sms2 <- d$B[n]
    sms3 <- d$C[n]
    sms <- paste(sms1, sms2, sms3, sep=" ")
    # here I would use the POST() function of httr to send a personalized SMS, but that is not important
  }
}
```

But I know this will not work. My `d` in `sms1 <- d$A[n]` will not be read as `sms1 <- df1$A[n]` or `sms1 <- df2$A[n]`.

Is there a way to do this loop? Better yet, what is the correct apply method?

**Update:**

Here is an example of the POST step I need to do to every row in both dataframes to send a personalized message to every person (row):

```
# let's say that sms3 in my example is a phone number
# let's also say that I define the following objects once outside of the loop:
  # url, username, password, account, source, network

# when I paste together the following objects, I get string that is formatted for my API gateway. 
send <- paste0(url, username, password, account, source, sms3, 
                 sms, network)
POST(send)
```

This would go in the loop as mentioned in comments from my original post:

```
# remove these paste steps from the loops as recommended in the answers
df1$sms <- paste(df2$A, df2$B)
df2$sms <- paste(df2$A, df2$B)

dfs <- c("df1", "df2")

# loop over dfs
for (d in dfs) {
  for (n in 1:nrow(d)) {
    sms3 <- d$C[n] # to get phone number
    send <- paste0(url, username, password, account, source, sms3, sms, network)
    POST(send)
  }
}
```

Comment: unlike most scripting languages `r` is functional. it takes getting use to but once you do - it's hard to look back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to loop through each row to `paste` elements together. Instead, you can just call `paste` once for each data frame:

```
df1$sms <- paste(df1$A, df1$B, df1$C)
```

You can then take this and create `df1$send` by calling `paste` again, or you can just use one `paste`, depending on your specific needs.

Now that you have everything you need in `df1$send`, you can just call `POST` on each element. `POST` is not vectorized, so you do have to iterate over the elements somehow. For example:

```
sapply(df1$send, POST)
```

You could do this again for `df2`, but another way would be to create a list of data frames, and loop over that, doing the same `paste` operation for each data frame. For example:

```
my.dfs <- list(df1, df2)
for (df in my.dfs) {
  df$sms <- paste(df$A, df$B, df$C)
  ...
  sapply(df$send, POST)
}
```

(You *could* also loop over characters strings of names, like you did originally, and then get the actual object corresponding to each string: `df <- get(d)`. But I see no reason here to prefer this.)

An even better way would to be to just combine `df1` and `df2` into a single data frame. You can create a column to distinguish the two groups. Then you'll only have to `paste` and `POST` on one data frame:

```
comprehensive.df$sms <- paste(comprehensive.df$A, comprehensive.df$B, comprehensive.df$C)
...
sapply(comprehensive.df$send, POST)
```

How you do this depends on how different your data frames are. If they are only slightly different, you could use `rbind.fill` from `plyr`, which handles missing columns. If they have different column names, etc., you could extract the common columns and do some renaming. I just think that if you do cleaning and combining before you get to the meat of the operation, what you're doing will be clearer.

It's okay to use `for` loops. In fact, if you look at the source for `apply`, you'll see that it makes use of `for` loops. The real gain comes not from using `apply`, but from taking advantage of vectorization by passing whole objects to functions, as is done above with `paste`. This is more readable (because it's a single, straightforward line) and will probably perform better (because you're only calling the function *once*).

Comment: Thanks, @Peyton. I think you make a good point about using one paste() step without having to loop through each row. But how do I do the step where I want to do something to each `sms` from every row of both datasets? For instance, in my case, I want to loop through every row and run a POST() command from the `httr` package which makes a call to an SMS gateway's API. For a few uninteresting reasons, I have to run POST() once for every phone number, which means once for every row. Each dataset in my real case has a different structure, so I figured I would need to also loop across datasets.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a `POST` call that is run on one row of your dataset?

Comment: So `POST` just takes one argument? And this is `sms` from the loop/`paste`? You could loop over `sms` and call `POST` on each element, or you could use `sapply(sms, POST)`.

Comment: And do the structures of your data frames really vary wildly? It might be easiest to extract and possibly rename the common elements and create one data frame for this purpose. Though looping over the different data frames would still work.

Comment: `POST` takes one argument: `send` from the loop. I guess I could get everything into one dataframe. Then I could use sapply as you suggest. One thing: Would I need to df1$send <- send and then `sapply(df1$send, POST)`?

Comment: That's probably the best way. I'll edit my answer to include all this.

Comment: in your revised answer, I think you need to use `send` not `sms` in the POST(). To incorporate all of the elements: df1$sms <- paste(df1$A, df1$B, sep=" ") and then df1$send <- paste0(url, username, password, account, source, df1$sms3, df1$sms, network) and then sapply(df1$send, POST).

Comment: Ah, right. I thought `send` replaced `sms`, but I see it doesn't.

Comment: when you say "You could do this again for df2, but another way would be to create a list of data frames, and loop over that, doing the same paste operation for each data frame", how would you do this? Gets back to my original question about how to loop over dataframes and refer to columns in the dataframes

Comment: The easiest way would be to just use a loop, like you did, but maybe modify it slightly to iterate over a list of data frames, rather than a list of data frame names. I included an example. (Also, one thing to note: there are some additional ways to approach your problem, but at the end of the day, use whatever makes sense to you.)

Answer (score 3):

Just rbind your data.frames instead of looping:

```
df <- rbind(df1, df2)
df$sms <- paste(df$A, df$B, df$C)
```